# kickstart from USB stick with RPMs not in ISO (CentOS5.x)

Tags: linux, centos5, kickstart

We have been looking to setup a USB disk (stick) for uniformly configuring our servers.
(and when I say "we" I mean my colleague figured it out with my occasional help)

We would like to explicitly list the RPMs we want.

So far:

- We managed to make the stick bootable
- We managed to configure grub to point at the kickstart file
- We placed a ISO (of the distro or one we created) containing the RPMs on the stick

I would like to avoid the step of creating this ISO image and just drop RPMs into a directory on the USB stick

I remember working with kickstart many years ago (probably with floppy) and am pretty sure  that this was possible.

**EDIT**

Maybe our problem is elsewhere ... we are getting the following screen, where it is specifically looking for an ISO image (re my original question - wanting to kickstart without an ISO image)

Here is a screen-shot of it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kickstart can install packages from any configured repository. Simply mount the USB key at a known location before the actual install and point the repo information to the appropriate directory (and don't forget to use `createrepo`).

Comment: @Ignacio I imagine that the system being bootstrapped has no OS present to mount on.

Comment: @JeffG: The installer has an OS.

Comment: We are specifying the path to the kickstart file in terms of an absolute device path ... something in the spirit of `ks=hd:sda1:/ks.cfg` ... how would I mount (from  %pre rule in kickstart?)

Comment: @nhed: Yes, that would be the appropriate place.

Comment: @Ignacio, thanks - but I am still unclear about 2 things:  (1) why should I mount if it is mounted already (ks file: install => --partiton & --dir)  (2) the what the directory tree should look like in said directory ... If you have dome this before can you paste an example?  Thanks

Comment: If it's already mounted then it's already mounted and Bob's your uncle. Run `createrepo` against the directory containing your RPMs, and then point the repo information to that directory.

Comment: @Ignacio see my edit above ... It just keep looking for ISO images ... is it possible to have just the RPMs in a directory?  if so can you provide an example

Comment: That's how hard drive installs work. Point the installer at the partition that contains the CentOS ISO.

Comment: So the answer to my question above should have been "it cant be done, you need the ISO"

Comment: Sure. But you don't need to have the RPMs in the ISO. All you need is the install ISO, and then you can have the RPMs in a repository on the key.

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck burning the ISO onto a DVD.

1. loopback mount your DVD ISO image
2. copy your kickstart file to the root of the image
3. edit isolinux/isolinux.cfg and append `ks=FILENAME.ks` to the kernel line
4. unmount the ISO image and burn the disk.

Comment: but I want it on a USB stick ... I'll edit my question for uniformity